# Fill missing values by group using most frequent value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, nan, imputation

I am trying to impute missing values using the most frequent value by a group using the `pandas` module in Python. After checking some posts on Stack Overflow, I have managed to achieve that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   "value": [1, 1, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan]})
df.groupby("group").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
```

Running this code will fill with 1 the missing entry for group "A" and with 2 both missing entries for group "B". However, let's assume that one of the groups contains only missing data (in this case group "B"):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   "value": [1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
df1.groupby("group").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
```

Running the code above will prompt an `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. I would expect the normal behaviour is to keep np.nan because if you run the method `mode` for just, let's say, group "B" from `df1`:

```
df1[df1.group == "B"].mode()
```

I will get that NaN is the most common value. How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running the code above will prompt an IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

This is because `transform` gets to be passed each column as a *series* and at some point it will see the `value` column on its own; and if you do:

```py
df1[df1.group == "B"].value.mode()
```

you get

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

hence the index-out-of-bounds like error as it is empty and `iloc[0]` doesn't exist.

OTOH, when you do:

```py
df1[df1.group == "B"].mode()
```

`mode` is calculated on a dataframe not a series and pandas decides to give a NaN on the full-NaN column i.e. `value` column here.

So one remedy is to use `apply` instead of `transform` to pass a dataframe instead of individual series to your `lambda`:

```py
df1.groupby("group").apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

to get

```
  group  value
0     A    1.0
1     A    1.0
2     A    1.0
3     A    1.0
4     B    NaN
5     B    NaN
6     B    NaN
```